# $\dot u(t) = - \nabla V(u(t)) $ unique solution if $V$ is convex

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, gradient-flows

I found this statement in a book I am reading:

> If $V: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and convex, then the differential equation $$\dot u(t) = - \nabla V(u(t)) $$
>   has a unique solution $u: [0, + \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for every initial value $u_0$.

How can I prove it?

Comment: Did you tried something?

Comment: What's the name of the book?

Answer (score 2):

I think the standard Gronwall's argument will work:

Let $u$ and $v$ be two solutions of the same initial value problem, and let $w = u - v$. Then $w(0) = 0$ and $w$ satisfies

$$
w' = u' - v' = -\nabla V u + \nabla V v.
$$

Now, consider $f(t) =  \left<w(t),w(t)\right>$, we want to show this is zero. We know that $f(0) = 0$. Calculating $f'$ gives
$$
f'(t) = 2\left<w'(t),w(t)\right> = -2\left<\nabla V u - \nabla V v,u - v\right> \leq - 2 C \left<u-v,u-v\right> = -2C f(t)
$$
by the definition of convexity.

Now, just use Gronwall's inequality to complete the proof.

Comment: Why is also the existence of the solution granted?

Comment: Existence has mild requirements in comparison; you just need $\nabla V$ to be continuous. 

Basically, a fixed-point argument will work: you want to show that the map $y(t) \mapsto y(0) + \int_0^t -\nabla V(y(s)) \ ds$ has a fixed point (such a fixed point will be a solution of the DE, as you can easily check).

Look up "Picard iteration", "Peano existence", etc. to get a flavor for how these arguments work, then see if you can prove it yourself.

Comment: What is $C$ above?